# Ignoring a delimiter in a string between ()

Tags: delimiter, alteryx

In Alteryx I need to parse a string that is ; delimited, but the data is constructed in a way that there are extra ; between brackets () when there are multiple outputs.

I found this expression for RegEx (;*)+(?![^{]*}) which would work if the ; was between {} but I can’t figure out how to sub out () to make it work.

Data strings look like
Corp Other Matters (Board; Mgmt); Board (Replace); Strategy(Change)
Corp Other Matters (Board); Strategy (Change; Shift)

I’d like an output with
Corp Other Matters (Board; Mgmt)    Board (Replace) Strategy(Change)
Corp Other Matters (Board)  Strategy (Change; Shift)

Bonus points if there’s a way to then create entries for
Corp Other Matters (Board)
Corp Other Matters (Mgmt)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Text To Column tool with configuration below:

- Delimiter ;
- Split to columns 4
- Check the box "Ignore delimiters in parentheses"

Then use the Formula tool to concatenate the 4 string fields.

Input:
Corp Other Matters (Board; Mgmt); Board (Replace); Strategy(Change) Corp Other Matters (Board); Strategy (Change; Shift)

Output:
Corp Other Matters (Board; Mgmt) Board (Replace) Strategy(Change) Corp Other Matters (Board) Strategy (Change; Shift)

[Text To Column tool configuration.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arTKd.png)

[Formula tool configuration.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SE3sl.png)